# the fundamental representation of SU(2) and quaternionic left multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quaternions

It is well known that $SU(2)$ and the unit quaternions $S^3\subset\mathbb{H}$ are isomorphic Lie groups.

SU(2) has a standard representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (via left matrix multiplication) and $S^3$ has a standard representation on $\mathbb{H}$ via left multiplication.

Are these representations isomorphic? (here they just affirm that it is the quaternionic multiplication without specifying if they mean the left or the right one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)#Most_important_irreducible_representations_and_their_applications)

What is the explicit isomorphism of $\mathbb{C^2}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ which realizes such isomorphism?

Comment: Only left multiplication will give you a representation (think about it).  To answer the first question, decompose into irreducibles or compute weight vectors, and use the classification of irreps of SU(2).  This should also help you with the second question.

Comment: Multiplying quaternions on the right by complex scalars turns $\Bbb H$ into a complex 2D vector space, hence isomorphic to $\Bbb C^2$. You can use e.g. $\{1,{\bf j}\}$ as a basis. Define $L_x(y)=xy$. Then $L_x$ is a linear operator on $\Bbb H$ (follows from associativity; check) so can be represented as a $2\times 2$ complex matrix. This gives a map $\Bbb H\to M_2(\Bbb C)$, and if you explicitly write it out, you set you get a map $S^3\to SU(2)$ which you can check is onto by finding the general form of an element of $SU(2)$.

Comment: The representations are "equivalent" in the sense that we can build a commutative diagram with $S^3\times\Bbb H\to\Bbb H$ up top, $SU(2)\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C^2$ down below, and vertical isomorphisms from the top row to the bottom.